# How do I update the javascript in my index.html file?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am currently making a flask app. I cant get the javascript to update whenever I do a post request. It just stays the same. Here is the code I am focused on that is supposed to update whenever I do a post request:

```
var jsonz = {{ entries|tojson }};
var s = JSON.parse(jsonz);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode(s[i].product_name + "\n" + s[i].product_link);
  para.appendChild(node);

  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para);
```

I am very new to javascript. I want to pass in "entries" from the back end and then have that json be displayed in the index.html.

Someone please help.

Here is the full code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flask app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <form class = "form" action="/index" method="POST">
      <input id ="textbox" name="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <p id="search-query"> you searched: </p>

  <div id="div1">
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
  </div>

<script>

var value = $('.textbox').val();
//alert(value);
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $("#textbox").val();
    //alert(value);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "index",
      data: JSON.stringify({"text" : value}),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data){
        $("#search-query").text("you search: " + data["text"]);
          //alert(JSON.stringify(data));

      }
    });
});

var jsonz = {{ entries|tojson }};
var s = JSON.parse(jsonz);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode(s[i].product_name + "\n" + s[i].product_link);
  para.appendChild(node);

  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para);
  }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is app.py

```
from scraper import scrape
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, make_response, request
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.get_json()

        search = json.dumps(search)
        search = json.loads(search)
        search = search['text']
        print search
        #search = json.loads(search)
        entries = json.dumps(scrape(search))
        return entries

    elif request.method == "GET":


        entries = json.dumps(scrape("cars"))
        return render_template('index.html', entries= entries)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Again, I want the scraped data in the form of "entries" to be passed to the front end and displayed in the html.

Thanks for any help!

HERES WHAT I DID TO FINALLY GET IT WORKING

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flask app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <form class = "form" action="/index" method="POST">
      <input id ="textbox" name="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <p id="search-query"> search results: </p>

  <div id="div1">
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
  </div>

<script>

var value = $('.textbox').val();
//alert(value);
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $("#textbox").val();
    alert(value);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "parse_data",
      data: JSON.stringify({"text" : value}),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data){
        $("p#search-query").append(data.data);

        alert(JSON.parse(data));

      }
    });
});




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and app.py

```
from scraper import scrape
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, make_response, request
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/parse_data", methods=['POST'])
def parse_data():

    search = request.get_json()

    search = json.dumps(search)
    search = json.loads(search)
    search = search['text']
    print search
    #search = json.loads(search)
    entries = json.dumps(scrape(search))
    #entries = jsonify({'name' : entries})
    return jsonify({'data' : render_template('response.html', entries= entries)})




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: I updated the OP to include what I did to get it working. Basically I had to pass the html page and the variables together as a json object. I am not sure if this is ideal but thats what worked for me.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but looks like the for loop you use to update the DOM is only executed once when the file is loaded. You need to place that code in a function (i.e. 'update_dom') and call that from your success function.

Comment: @DannyMoshe Yeah i tried putting the javascript inside the success function but it didnt do anything. Instead I ended up creating a separate html file and appending that html to the index.html page.